# Linux Cryptsetup LuksOpen

Tags: linux, lvm

Нужно было Изменить размер логического раздела в зашифрованом разделе LVM. Пользуясь инструкцией (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) Дошел до момента
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 - Но luks*Open* - среди команд нет. Если у вас есть мысли как расшифровать диск для последующей работы с ним, или другой способ изменить логический раздел прошу рассазать.  Спасибо!

```
$sudo cryptsetup  luksDump /dev/nvme0n1p3 

LUKS header information                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Version:        2                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Epoch:          3                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
UUID:           8cd7ee1f-2cbd-4fc6-983a-efc0fb2a9d2e                                                                                                                                                                                       
Label:          (no label)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Flags:          (no flags)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Data segments:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  0: crypt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        length: (whole device)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        sector: 512 [bytes]                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Keyslots:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  0: luks2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Key:        512 bits                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        Priority:   normal                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        Cipher key: 512 bits                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        PBKDF:      argon2i                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Time cost:  4                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        Memory:     748534                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Threads:    4                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        Salt:       a3 56 81 94 f3 cc c3 e0 b8 db 9f ce e4 d9 6c b6 
                    e6 ed 8a 6b 3c 51 2d 83 55 22 c6 03 7f 90 68 ae 
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 231575
        Salt:       01 44 55 a6 b5 33 f2 fd 65 01 7c 94 ba e0 0a 91 
                    a1 b0 4d a8 bd 4b cb de 23 e4 e6 f7 c4 a9 5e 0e 
        Digest:     db af f2 7f d2 01 47 8b 26 9e ca 4a 87 59 e2 fe 
                    4e 4e 89 b1 78 7c c1 c9 af 4d bb 05 6d f8 fc 54
```

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: BC511 NVMe SK hynix 256GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D9475C1D-152E-444A-BAE0-B66A3198E9F7

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2050048 500118158 498068111 237.5G Linux filesystem
```

/dev/nvme0n1p3 - Зашифрованный раздел с / и /home (отдельные логические разделы)

/dev/nvme0n1p2 - Зашифрованный ключ от /dev/nvme0n1p3

> На теги LUKS и cryptsetup репутации не хватает

Comment: Хотел добавить - Систему загрузить не получиться я с дуру логический том с системой переполнил поэтому сижу с live cd

Comment: систему можно загрузить `init=/bin/bash`, потом `mount -a` и `mount -o remounr,rw /` попробовать почистить /var/log и /var/cache

Comment: Делал! Но не помогло.... Xsession не может записать ничего в /tmp. Пробовал через безопаный режим в консоли, тоже не получаеться (lvm2 cryptsetup нужно установить, а некуда) Удалять что то не хотелось бы